# Iterate over all the other objects excluding the current one

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, foreach, nested-loops

In many applications is necessary to compute the mutual interactions between a sequence of objects, that is for each object of the sequence, iterate over all the other objects except/skipping/excluding the current one.
That's my current solution to this:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
for( auto icurr=objects.begin(); icurr!=objects.end(); ++icurr )
   {// Iterate over all the other objects excluding this one
    for( auto iother=objects.begin(); iother!=icurr; ++iother )
        icurr->interact_with(*iother);
    for( auto iother=icurr+1; iother!=objects.end(); ++iother )
        icurr->interact_with(*iother);
   }
```

But this doesn't satisfy me because it's cumbersome and above all duplicates the loop body.
I don't like the banal alternative either:

```
for( auto icurr=objects.begin(); icurr!=objects.end(); ++icurr )
   {
    for( auto iother=objects.begin(); iother!=objects.end(); ++iother )
        if(icurr!=iother) icurr->interact_with(*iother);
   }
```

Because has an avoidable test; in that case, I would rather write something like:

```
for( Object& curr : objects )
   {
    for( const Object& other : objects.excluded(curr) )
        curr.interact_with(other);
   }
```

If it would have the same performance, that would be a major readability gain. Can I take advantage of the latest c++ standard to improve the readability my code? Any advice?
Disclaimer: this is a coding style question, an attempt to keep updated on best practices, learn and improve.

Comment: I think something like `objects.excluded(curr)` would be even worse, since that function needs to create an extra temprary range to satisfy the range based loop requirements. Are there any measurements you have performance or memory wise, which can show that the alternative solutions you have are bad? Or is it only the readability which bothers you here?

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I was was wondering if there was some best practice about this that maximizes readability and performance

Comment: [`std::ranges::filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) (C++20)? range-v3 before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With range libraries, you might do something like:

```
for (const Object& curr : objects) {
    for (const Object& other : objects | ranges::filter([&](const Object& obj) { return &obj != curr; }) )
        curr.interact_with(other);
   }
```

but that would indeed do extra comparison.

Your first version seems optimal.
With [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20) (or reimplemented version), you might do, to avoid duplication, something like:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
for (auto it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it) {
    for (auto range : {std::span{objects.begin(), it}, std::span{it + 1, objects.end()}}) {
        for (const auto& other : range) {
             it->interact_with(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting, I will definitely experiment with your snippets and let you know!

Comment: Your snippet compiles and works out of the box, tested [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qfj55fvTz). I still have to compare the generated assembler, but this new idiom seems quite powerful and expressive

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would write an overall separate excludes function because then you end up re-allocating the whole objects vector minus one element. Don't over engineer what can be done with a index based for loop.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
        if (i == j) continue;
        objects[i].interact_with(objects[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer, keep it simple is often a good advice, but please don't use indexed loops with std containers without a particular reason to, and don't make your compiler suffer with those sloppy postfix increments :-) But I get your undelying message

Comment: @MatG The way you use std::vector will make the compiler suffer. Postfix incrementing an integer definitely will not.

Comment: As long as you are using a vector it is fine to use index based iteration. Only associative stl containers need iterators really. Also as Stuntddude mentioned, postfix increment is just style it will not mess with the compiler. Also we have a particular reason here to use an index based loop, we want the index for cheap comparisons.

Comment: @jack That was a joke, it's just that I prefer to use the postfix increment only when is actually needed, for clarity. Thank you again for your time and effort, I didn't know that comparing size_t was cheaper than comparing iterators, I will definitely check in compiler explorer!

Comment: @Stuntddude I know I shouldn't comment to say just a thank you, but... Thank you for your comment, that made my day!

Comment: Cheap was the wrong word to use, I meant simple comparison. There is nothing cheaper about comparing size_t than comparing pointers (they are the same size usually).